# Should I list my boss as an emergency contact for college?

Tags: professionalism, management, employees, sickness, student

I checked around the site and didn't find an answer to this (apologies if there's an answer I missed). Here's the situation:

I attend one college as a student while working in academic support at another college. I work with students who depend on me to be present for regularly scheduled sessions throughout the semester. It'd mess them up pretty bad if something kept me from showing up for work.

Every year, the college I attend makes us update our emergency contact (ICE) info. I have a long commute and I had a close call recently, so I've started thinking seriously about who needs to know if something happened to me. Needless to say, I'd want my boss to know ASAP, for her sake and for my students'. Up to now I've just filled in the ICE form with my parents' contact info, but I'm not sure I could count on them to remember to contact my boss, even if I write it down somewhere.

**Would it be weird to list my boss as an ICE contact with the college I attend so they can notify her if something happens to me?** I feel like it's a sensible thing to do, but inexperience makes me wonder if I've overlooked some reason that it's a bad idea. Of course I'd let her know beforehand and double-check which phone number/etc. she'd prefer I give them.

If it *would* be weird, what can I do instead to make sure someone contacts her if I'm incapacitated?

Answer (score 9):

Emergency contacts are normally people who are very close friends or relatives who can come collect you, bring clothes or personal items to hospital if needed, or notify other people.

Unless your boss is someone who fits this category, I would probably not list them as an emergency contact as it will probably make her very uncomfortable.  Use friends or family who can notify your boss if something happens.

Answer (score 5):

**No you shouldn't.** Emergency contacts should be reserved for family and close friends who will drop everything to help you out if something serious were to happen to you. It's not a list of people to contact should you fall ill. Should anything happen that requires the university to use your In Case of Emergency (ICE) info, they will almost certainly stop after reaching the first person in the list who is available to help, rightly assuming that that person will contact other people or family members as necessary.

If you are worried about your ICE contacts not notifying your employer, **you should draft your own ICE document**. That document should contain a brief medical history (allergies, known averse reactions to medications, blood type, ...), insurance info, family doctor, a list of people to contact should you be incapacitated and unable to reach out yourself, donor consent/refusal and location of your will if you're feeling fatalistic, and anything else you deem relevant. Provide that document to all your ICE contacts so they have everything they need should you be unfortunate enough to find yourself in the hospital. You may get some comments about being Crazy Prepared but **if anything should ever happen you and your ICE contact will both be glad that you had this information available in one place.**

Answer (score 2):

Emergency contacts are usually wanted so the proper people can get in touch with those who would be helpful **to you** in case an unfortunate event were to happen to **you.** I'm thinking stuff like you're unconscious in the hospital and you need someone to make decisions.

Listing your boss, because she (and others) would be inconvenienced due to an emergency situation befalling you, seems to sort of be missing the point of why colleges ask for an emergency contacts list. It'd probably annoy (or worse: delay) whomever was trying to get in touch with your next of kin during an emergency.

That being said, I think it's fine, and not weird if both parties agree. You can ask your boss about it, and if you both feel that would be appropriate then all is good.